# How does adjustwidth affect \par and \write?

Tags: paragraphs, write

With the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\newoutputstream{info}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.info}{info}

\section{First}
Here's some text to fill things up.
\addtostream{info}{This is the first bit: \thesection.\par}

\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}
\section{Second}
Here's some text to fill things up.

\addtostream{info}{This is the second bit: \thesection.\par}
\end{adjustwidth}

\section{Third}
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
Here's some text to fill things up.
\addtostream{info}{This is the third bit: \thesection.\par}
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}

\closeoutputstream{info}

\section{Extra Information}
\input{\jobname.info}
\end{document}
```

I get the following output, where the `\par` in the first and third section's `\addtostream` are written to the output file correctly. However in the second section, which is within a `adjustwidth`, the `\par` gets printed as `@par` in the output:

[image: Note the <code>@par</code> after "This is the second bit: 2."]

Is `adjustwidth` doing anything to `\par` that's causing this? How can I write `\par` to the output file correctly when I'm in an `adjustwidth` environment?

(You can edit the code here directly: https://www.overleaf.com/6014969bzsxfx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a `list` environment (or one based on it, such as `adjustwidth`), `\par` is redefined, as testified by the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

{\ttfamily\meaning\par}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item {\ttfamily\meaning\par}
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are several good reasons for this, that you can read in `source2e.pdf` (run `texdoc source2e` from a command line).

Use `\noexpand\par`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\newoutputstream{info}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.info}{info}

\section{First}
Here's some text to fill things up.
\addtostream{info}{This is the first bit: \thesection.\noexpand\par}

\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}
\section{Second}
Here's some text to fill things up.

\addtostream{info}{This is the second bit: \thesection.\noexpand\par}
\end{adjustwidth}

\section{Third}
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
Here's some text to fill things up.
\addtostream{info}{This is the third bit: \thesection.\noexpand\par}
\end{minipage}

\closeoutputstream{info}

\section{Extra Information}
\input{\jobname.info}
\end{document}
```

Here's the contents of the `.info` file

```
This is the first bit: 1.\par 
This is the second bit: 2.\par 
This is the third bit: 3.\par
```

Alternatively, use `^^J` instead of `\noexpand\par`, which will add a blank line in the `.info` file

```
This is the first bit: 1.

This is the second bit: 2.

This is the third bit: 3.
```

Comment: Works perfectly — and I learnt `\meaning`! Thank you.